# Tthe namespace equivalent of the static operator for classes in PHP?

Tags: php, namespaces

The documentation says

> The ***namespace*** keyword can be used to explicitly request an element from the current namespace or a sub-namespace. It is the namespace equivalent of the ***self*** operator for classes.

I need the equivalent of ***static*** instead, ie. if a class extends my class, the namespace of that.

This

```
 return preg_replace('/.[^\\\\]+$/', '', get_class($object));
```

does it but it makes me sad.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Reflection provides an effective way of doing this via `ReflectionObject->getNamespace()`, check the following code:

```
namespace Foo {
    class Bar {
        public function getNamespace() {
            return (new \ReflectionObject($this))->getNamespaceName();
        }
    }
}

namespace Baz {
    use Foo\Bar as BaseClass;

    class Bar extends BaseClass {}
}

namespace {
    $bar1 = new Foo\Bar();
    echo "ns1 is: ", $bar1->getNamespace(), '<br>';

    $bar2 = new Baz\Bar();
    echo "ns2 is: ", $bar2->getNamespace();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there's a "late static namespace" helper and you will indeed need to hack around.

e.g.

```
<?php

namespace ProjectFoo;

class Foo {
    public static function ns() { echo __NAMESPACE__; }
    public static function getNamespace() {
        return static::ns();
    }
}

namespace ProjectBar;
use ProjectFoo\Foo;

class Bar extends Foo {
    public static function ns() { echo __NAMESPACE__; }
}

$foo = new Foo();
$foo::getNamespace();
print "\n";

$bar = new Bar();
$bar::getNamespace();
print "\n";
```